# Rails 6 has_one through and polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got below models relations:

```
class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :walletable, polymorphic: true
end

class SpvSetup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio

  has_one  :wallet, as: :walletable
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :wallet, as: :walletable
end
```

Because `SpvSetup` belongs_to `Portfolio` I want to access to the `Portfolio` model from `Wallet` model through the `SpvSetup` to be able to do something like this:

```
wallet = Wallet.last
wallet.portfolio
```

To do so I've updated `Wallet` and `Portfolio` model like below:

```
class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :walletable, polymorphic: true
  has_one    :portfolio, through: :spv_setup, source: :walletable, source_type: 'Wallet'
end


class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :spv_setup, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wallet, through: :spv_setup, source: :walletable, source_type: 'Wallet'
end
```

But all I got was an error:

```
> wallet.portfolio

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the association :spv_setup in model Wallet)
Did you mean?  walletable
               transactions
               fake_wallet
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `delegate` for what you are trying to achieve.
for example:

```
class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :walletable, polymorphic: true

  delegate :portfolio, to: :spv_setup
end

class SpvSetup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio

  has_one  :wallet, as: :walletable
end
```

Above will let you do:

```
wallet = Wallet.last
wallet.portfolio
```

For more info check [this](https://medium.com/@pk60905/using-delegate-in-rails-527332da7f96)

Hope this helped.